# Android: Image upload to web-service loses EXIF data

Tags: java, android

Please help,

I currently upload an image to my web-service which does have the EXIF data attached to it at time of upload. When it arrives on the server, it is minus it's exif data.

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullFileName);
                  if (bmp == null) {
                    //oh sugar, not cool
                     continue;
                }
                  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
                  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("webserviceurl");
                ByteArrayEntity test = new ByteArrayEntity(byteArray){...}

     post.setEntity(test);
```

Before I upload the image, it's stored to the devices SD card to which is then decoded using the BitmapFactory class.

I'm thinking its during the image compression that its lost, anybody got a solution or idea ?

Thanks

Burrows111

Comment: Where exactly are you attaching the Exif data? You're decoding a file to bitmap (which loses the Exif data), then recompressing the bitmap to JPEG, without attaching Exif. Why not just send the file as is?

Comment: Ah, OK i didn't realise I was losing my EXIF during the decode. I need to compress the image to prevent large file uploads. Can you point me in the direction of image compression WITH exif. The Exif is attached when I take the photo using a custom Image Capture class. I can see the exif data on the stored image so we are cool knowing its there. Thanks for your help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html -- doubt it works on a stream though.

Comment: I set the EXIF using that class @323go - there is no method there to generate me a compressed image. Im not after a thumbnail.

Comment: You need to compress the image to the stream, write it to a file, set the Exif and then copy the file to the output stream.

Comment: @323go put it as an answer mate so i can tick the box! the solution worked, doesn't sound ideal but it's working nicely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXIF data is stripped during encode. However, [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) will allow you to set the EXIF data on the compressed file. Unfortunately, you'll need to compress the image, write it to a file, then set the EXIF on the file, and finally upload that.

Comment: Yeah correct, I compressed the image, saved it then wrote the exif data. Thanks for your help

Comment: @burrows111 , I am busy with the same problem. Can you please explain how you would go about saving the compressed bitmap to a file and then adding the exif data to that specific file. After this I still need to upload this to a server, in other words convert to a byte array. Please can you give a little more insight on this.

Comment: @Janpan I recently changed jobs so i have no access to the source of how i managed this. I see you asked the question anyway and got your response. Im sorry i was late replying.

Answer (score 1):

I made this so others don't have to go through the monotony...

```
public static void copyExifData(String file1, String file2){
        try {
            ExifInterface file1Exif = new ExifInterface(file1);
            ExifInterface file2Exif = new ExifInterface(file2);

            String aperture = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE);
            String dateTime = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
            String exposureTime = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME);
            String flash = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
            String focalLength = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
            String gpsAltitude = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE);
            String gpsAltitudeRef = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF);
            String gpsDateStamp = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
            String gpsLatitude = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            String gpsLatitudeRef = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            String gpsLongitude = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            String gpsLongitudeRef = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
            String gpsProcessingMethod = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);
            String gpsTimestamp = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
            Integer imageLength = file1Exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, 0);
            Integer imageWidth = file1Exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, 0);
            String iso = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO);
            String make = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
            String model = file1Exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
            Integer orientation = file1Exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Integer whiteBalance = file1Exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE, 0);


            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, orientation.toString());
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE, aperture);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, dateTime);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME, exposureTime);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH, flash);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, focalLength);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, gpsAltitude);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, gpsAltitudeRef);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP, gpsDateStamp);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, gpsLatitude);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, gpsLatitudeRef);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, gpsLongitude);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, gpsLongitudeRef);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD, gpsProcessingMethod);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, gpsTimestamp);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, imageLength.toString());
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, imageWidth.toString());
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO, iso);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, make);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, model);
            file2Exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE, whiteBalance.toString());
            file2Exif.saveAttributes();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException io) {}
        catch (IOException io) {}
        catch (NullPointerException np){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but I had to write a method to copy exif data in Kotlin and I thought it might be helpful to others.

```
import androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface

class ExifUtils {

    companion object {

        fun copyExif(src: ExifInterface, dest: ExifInterface) {

            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE_VALUE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE_VALUE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BITS_PER_SAMPLE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BODY_SERIAL_NUMBER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BODY_SERIAL_NUMBER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CAMERA_OWNER_NAME, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CAMERA_OWNER_NAME))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CFA_PATTERN, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CFA_PATTERN))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COLOR_SPACE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COLOR_SPACE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPONENTS_CONFIGURATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPONENTS_CONFIGURATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPRESSED_BITS_PER_PIXEL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPRESSED_BITS_PER_PIXEL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPRESSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COMPRESSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CONTRAST, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CONTRAST))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COPYRIGHT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COPYRIGHT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CUSTOM_RENDERED, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_CUSTOM_RENDERED))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DEFAULT_CROP_SIZE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DEFAULT_CROP_SIZE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DEVICE_SETTING_DESCRIPTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DEVICE_SETTING_DESCRIPTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DIGITAL_ZOOM_RATIO, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DIGITAL_ZOOM_RATIO))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DNG_VERSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DNG_VERSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXIF_VERSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXIF_VERSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_BIAS_VALUE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_BIAS_VALUE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_INDEX, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_INDEX))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_MODE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_MODE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_PROGRAM, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_PROGRAM))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FILE_SOURCE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FILE_SOURCE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASHPIX_VERSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASHPIX_VERSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH_ENERGY, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH_ENERGY))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_35MM_FILM))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_RESOLUTION_UNIT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_RESOLUTION_UNIT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_X_RESOLUTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_X_RESOLUTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_Y_RESOLUTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_PLANE_Y_RESOLUTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_F_NUMBER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_F_NUMBER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GAIN_CONTROL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GAIN_CONTROL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GAMMA, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GAMMA))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_AREA_INFORMATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_AREA_INFORMATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_BEARING_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_DISTANCE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_DISTANCE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_DISTANCE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_DISTANCE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LATITUDE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LATITUDE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LATITUDE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LATITUDE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LONGITUDE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LONGITUDE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LONGITUDE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DEST_LONGITUDE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DIFFERENTIAL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DIFFERENTIAL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DOP, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DOP))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_H_POSITIONING_ERROR, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_H_POSITIONING_ERROR))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_MAP_DATUM, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_MAP_DATUM))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_MEASURE_MODE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_MEASURE_MODE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SATELLITES, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SATELLITES))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SPEED, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SPEED))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SPEED_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SPEED_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_STATUS, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_STATUS))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TRACK, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TRACK))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TRACK_REF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TRACK_REF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_VERSION_ID, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_VERSION_ID))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_UNIQUE_ID, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_UNIQUE_ID))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_INTEROPERABILITY_INDEX, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_INTEROPERABILITY_INDEX))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED_LATITUDE_YYY, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED_LATITUDE_YYY))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED_LATITUDE_ZZZ, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO_SPEED_LATITUDE_ZZZ))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_JPEG_INTERCHANGE_FORMAT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_JPEG_INTERCHANGE_FORMAT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_JPEG_INTERCHANGE_FORMAT_LENGTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_JPEG_INTERCHANGE_FORMAT_LENGTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_MAKE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_MAKE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_MODEL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_MODEL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_SERIAL_NUMBER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_SERIAL_NUMBER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_SPECIFICATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LENS_SPECIFICATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LIGHT_SOURCE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LIGHT_SOURCE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKER_NOTE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKER_NOTE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAX_APERTURE_VALUE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAX_APERTURE_VALUE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_METERING_MODE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_METERING_MODE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_NEW_SUBFILE_TYPE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_NEW_SUBFILE_TYPE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_OECF, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_OECF))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_ASPECT_FRAME, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_ASPECT_FRAME))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_PREVIEW_IMAGE_LENGTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_PREVIEW_IMAGE_LENGTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_PREVIEW_IMAGE_START, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_PREVIEW_IMAGE_START))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORF_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PHOTOGRAPHIC_SENSITIVITY, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PHOTOGRAPHIC_SENSITIVITY))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PHOTOMETRIC_INTERPRETATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_X_DIMENSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_X_DIMENSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_Y_DIMENSION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_Y_DIMENSION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PLANAR_CONFIGURATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PLANAR_CONFIGURATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PRIMARY_CHROMATICITIES, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PRIMARY_CHROMATICITIES))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RECOMMENDED_EXPOSURE_INDEX, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RECOMMENDED_EXPOSURE_INDEX))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_REFERENCE_BLACK_WHITE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_REFERENCE_BLACK_WHITE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RELATED_SOUND_FILE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RELATED_SOUND_FILE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ROWS_PER_STRIP, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ROWS_PER_STRIP))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_ISO, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_ISO))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_JPG_FROM_RAW, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_JPG_FROM_RAW))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_BOTTOM_BORDER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_BOTTOM_BORDER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_LEFT_BORDER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_LEFT_BORDER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_RIGHT_BORDER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_RIGHT_BORDER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_TOP_BORDER, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_RW2_SENSOR_TOP_BORDER))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SATURATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SATURATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SCENE_CAPTURE_TYPE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SCENE_CAPTURE_TYPE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SCENE_TYPE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SCENE_TYPE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SENSING_METHOD, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SENSING_METHOD))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SENSITIVITY_TYPE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SENSITIVITY_TYPE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SHARPNESS, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SHARPNESS))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SOFTWARE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SOFTWARE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SPATIAL_FREQUENCY_RESPONSE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SPATIAL_FREQUENCY_RESPONSE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SPECTRAL_SENSITIVITY, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SPECTRAL_SENSITIVITY))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STANDARD_OUTPUT_SENSITIVITY, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STANDARD_OUTPUT_SENSITIVITY))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STRIP_BYTE_COUNTS, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STRIP_BYTE_COUNTS))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STRIP_OFFSETS, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_STRIP_OFFSETS))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBFILE_TYPE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBFILE_TYPE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_AREA, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_AREA))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_DISTANCE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_DISTANCE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_DISTANCE_RANGE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_DISTANCE_RANGE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_LOCATION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBJECT_LOCATION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_DIGITIZED, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_DIGITIZED))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_ORIGINAL, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME_ORIGINAL))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_LENGTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_LENGTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_WIDTH, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_WIDTH))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_TRANSFER_FUNCTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_TRANSFER_FUNCTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_POINT, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_POINT))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_XMP, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_XMP))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_X_RESOLUTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_X_RESOLUTION))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_COEFFICIENTS, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_COEFFICIENTS))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_POSITIONING, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_POSITIONING))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_SUB_SAMPLING, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_CB_CR_SUB_SAMPLING))
            dest.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION, src.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION))

            dest.saveAttributes()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) API instead of `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`. It doesn't omit exif.

```
val source: ImageDecoder.Source = ImageDecoder.createSource(file)
val outBitmap: Bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
```